# How to use sql result stored on shell variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, shell

I know now how to store the result of sql procédure in shell variable

```
testvar=$(sqlplus foo/bar @test.sql)
```

my test.sql return a list of integer that i would use in another select calling by my shell.
The aim of this procedure is to show the progress avancement of my treatment like

```
x=0;
while x <testvar.size
sqlplus foo/bar @test2.sql $testvar.x
print (x*100/testvar.size + "%")
end while
```

(i dont know shell programming but it's easiest than my current problem...

Comment: I'm using bash script and I don't even know how to make it but i have people around me to help me on that but no on this problem

Comment: I am not familiar with the output of `sqlplus`. Could you paste some sample output when you run it with your script as input? If so I can tell you how to parse it form bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output of `sqlplus` is literally "A list of integers" as you describe, then this is easy enough.

```
SOMETHING=5

while -r read n ; do
    if [ $n -ge $SOMETHING ] ; then
        break
    fi
    sqlplus foo/bar @test2.sql "$n"
    printf '%.2f%%\n' $(expr "$n" \* 100 / "$SOMETHING")
done < <(sqlplus foo/bar @test.sql)
```

Presuming that "A list of integers" really means "A newline separated list of integers"

It's not clear to me what `$testvar.x` and `testvar.size` are supposed to represent, so I made some guesses and left the variable `$SOMETHING` to stand in for whatever testvar.size is supposed to be. If you want the total number of integers in the list from `sqlplus` then that would be different, and done like this:

```
intlist=($(sqlplus foo/bar @test.sql))

for n in "${intlist[@]}"; do
    if [ $n -ge ${#intlist[@]} ] ; then
        break
    fi
    sqlplus foo/bar @test2.sql "$n"
    printf '%.2f%%\n' $(expr "$n" \* 100 / ${#intlist[@]})
done < <(sqlplus foo/bar @test.sql)
```

If your output is more complex some additional filtering will need to be done up front.

Comment: the second option is litteraly what I needed ! My test.sql is a select on id from a table.
I'm home know but i'll make it tomorrow and tell you how I use it.